# WPF MultiBinding fails in Syncfusion TabItemExt header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding, syncfusion

I have a subclass of `TabItem` as follows, for which I'm trying to set the `Header` property. I've tried this with a `MultiBinding`:

```
<DataEditPane x:TypeArguments="MyType" x:Class="MyDataEditPane">
    <DataEditPane.Header>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Hello world {0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="BoundVariable1" />
            <Binding Path="BoundVariable2" />
        </MultiBinding>    
    </DataEditPane.Header>
</DataEditPane>
```

But it fails as such:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 28 : MultiBinding failed because it has no valid Converter. MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'MyDataEditPane' (Name=''); target property is 'Header' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Error: 28 : MultiBinding failed because it has no valid Converter. MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'MyDataEditPane' (Name=''); target property is 'Header' (type 'Object')
```

I'd always thought the `StringFormat` served the role of the converter, but perhaps not?

Wrapping the fields together in some kind of container, like a `Label`, also doesn't seem to work:

```
<DataEditPane x:TypeArguments="MyType" x:Class="MyDataEditPane">
    <DataEditPane.Header>
        <Label>
            <Label.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="Hello world {0} {1}">
                    <Binding Path="BoundVariable1" />
                    <Binding Path="BoundVariable2" />
                </MultiBinding>    
            </Label.Text>
        </Label>
    </DataEditPane.Header>
</DataEditPane>
```

In this case, the `.ToString()` representation of the label ("`System.Windows.Controls.Label`") is shown as the header.

Note that a single binding works just fine:

```
<DataEditPane x:TypeArguments="MyType" x:Class="MyDataEditPane">
    <DataEditPane.Header>
        <Binding Path="BoundVariable1" />
    </DataEditPane.Header>
</DataEditPane>
```

If it matters, I'm using the Syncfusion `TabItemExt` as one of my superclasses in the inheritance hierarchy, but as that class doesn't override the `Header` property I don't think that makes a difference.

What am I doing wrong? I know I can make another property in the ViewModel to act as the Header (and then single-bind that) but I want to learn how to do this properly in XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-Bindings requires a converter, i think that a converter that you may use is the `StringFormatConverter`, it is a `IMultiValueConverter` so works for multibindings.
Maybe you should adapt it to your case.

Hope this could be useful for you...

Comment: Yeah, it looks like my hope of doing this in XAML only without a Converter has been dashed. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Just to be clear - a Multibinding doesn't require a converter. StringFormat works fine if you bind to a property of type string. In this case the Syncfusion TabItemExt control apparently calls ToString on whatever is inside the header, but that has nothing to do with the binding.

Comment: Yes, you don't need write explicit in your XML code if is a string type property. But in fact, all Bindings have a converter, but in most cases WPF use a default Converter. In this case, when is a string type property, it use the default converter (i think is the StringFormatConverter)

Answer (score 4):

Try a TextBlock instead of a Label. The following code worked fine for me.

I tried this:

```
<Window x:Class="ListBox.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBox" Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:TextVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text1}"  />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text2}" />
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="Hello World {0} - {1}">
                    <Binding Path="Text1" />
                    <Binding Path="Text2" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I wonder if StringFormat is only valid in cases where a string is expected rather than an object.

There's an example on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but no dice. Putting your XAML inside the `<DataEditPane.Header>` tag just shows `System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel` in the header. Something about the Header property is only allowing text.